# Remove Items from Mass Action Menu

Tags: magento2, php, module

I am using the following to remove an Item from the Mass Action menu in the orders screen, I am struggling with making it work for multiple items.

```
class MassAction extends \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction
{
    private $authorization;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
            \Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
            array $components,
            array $data
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepare() {
        parent::prepare();
        $config = $this->getConfiguration();
        $allowedActions = [];
        foreach ($config['actions'] as $action) {
            if ('cancel' != $action['type']) {
                $allowedActions[] = $action;
            }
        }
        $config['actions'] = $allowedActions;       
        $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
                parent::prepare();
        $config = $this->getConfiguration();
        $allowedActions = [];
        foreach ($config['actions'] as $action) {
            if ('hold_order' != $action['type']) {
                $allowedActions[] = $action;
            }
        }
        $config['actions'] = $allowedActions;
        $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
    }
}
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was some of the 'type' variables dont seem to work, if I use 'label' it works fine

```
foreach ($config['actions'] as $action) {
            if (('cancel' != $action['type']) and ('hold_order' != $action['type']) and ('unhold_order' != $action['type']) and ('Print Invoices' != $action['label']) and ('print_shipping_label' != $action['type']) and ('Print Packing Slips' != $action['label']) and ('Print Credit Memos' != $action['label']) and ('Print All' != $action['label'])) {
                $allowedActions[] = $action;
            }
```